# Given $(X,d)$ compact, find a countable set of functions to approximate any continuous function at finite points in $X$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be compact and $C(X)$ be the set of continuous function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$. Then clearly any $f \in C(X)$ is uniform continuous. Define $C_{m,n} = \{f(x) \in C(X) \colon d(x,y) < \frac 1m \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < \frac1n \}$.

Show that given any set of finite points $x_1, \cdots, x_k \in X$ and $m,n \geq 1$, there is a countable set $\{f_l\} \subseteq C_{m,n}$ so that for any $f \in C_{m,n}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $f_l \in C_{m,n}$ so that $\max_{i = 1,\cdots, k}|f_l(x_i)-f(x_i)| < \epsilon$.

It is easy to simply create many different countable set of functions s.t. $f_{l}(x_i) = r_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $f_l$ is continuous and since rational is dense in real most conditions can be satisfied. The problem is how to ensure $f_l \in C_{m,n}$. I wonder how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\Bbb Q^{k+1}$. For every $l=(r,y_1,\ldots, y_k)\in I$ let
$$F_l=\{\,f\in C_{m,n}:\forall i\;|f(x_i)-y_i|\,\}.$$
It may happen that for some $l$, $F_l$ is empty; in fact, $F_l$ is *certainly* empty when $r\le 0$.
But for those $l$ with $F_l\ne\emptyset$, pick one arbitrary $f_l\in F_l$. This gives us our desired countable subset
$$Q:=\{\,f_l:l\in I, F_l\ne\emptyset\,\}$$
of $C_{m,n}$.

Now let $f\in C_{m,n}$ be arbitrary and $\epsilon>0$. Using denseness of $\Bbb Q$, pick $r \in \Bbb Q$ with  $0<r<\frac12\epsilon$ and then $y_i\in \Bbb Q$ with $|f(x_i)-y_i|<r$, and let $l=(r,y_1,\ldots, y_k)$. As $f\in F_l$ shows that $F_l\ne\emptyset$, there exists some $f_l\in Q\cap F_l$ and for this we have $|f(x_i)-f_l(x_i)|<2r<\epsilon$, as desired.